# Como enviar para email o conteúdo escrito em uma <textarea></textarea>?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, html5

Gostaria de saber, se existe por meio de algum script, um modo de enviar o conteúdo contido na "textarea" para um email. Desde já, grato!

Comment: Mostre o código que vc desenvolveu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode pegar o valor da `<textarea>` pelo método `POST` do `Form`, exemplo:

```
<form method="post" action="query.php">
    <textarea name="texto"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

E depois pegar com o `$_POST` do php:

```
$conteudo = $_POST['texto'];
```

E enviar o email normalmente:

```
mail($destinatario, $assunto, $conteudo, "From: joaolegal@gmail.com");
//Onde a variavel $assunto contem o assunto do email e $destinatario, pra quem o email será enviado
```

#### Não se esqueça de configurar o `php.ini`!

Veja [isso](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp), se se tiver mais duvidas. Ou a [documentação oficial](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php).